# What is the fallacy when trying to evaluate the FT of the dirac delta function via integration by parts?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

When evaluating the Fourier transform of the dirac delta function, if I call the dirac delta function dv as a basis to try to integrate by parts, then because the integral of the dirac delta function is 1 = v then all that is left is u - the integral of du which would reduce to 0. But the actual FT is 1. The same question would apply to ANY function with an integral of 1 across the real line (i.e. finite signal with total AOC of 1); there's no way the FTs are just 0. Where is the mistake in this reasoning? Is there an approach to evaluate the FT for any given function with an integral of 1?

Comment: Just use the property of Dirac delta function. $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm dx = f(a)$$

Comment: Your mistake is that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\,\mathrm dx = 1$, but while doing integration by parts, we don't apply the limits on the integral. Instead, we put the boundary terms on $uv$. For that, you have to use the indefinite integral of $\delta(x)$, which I don't think exists. Also, how can you say that the integral of $u$ will be $0$. Please clarify your question.

Comment: The integral of udv = uv - integral of vdu, but if v = 1, then this would simplify to u - integral of du and thus u - u across whatever boundary (in this case negative infinity to positive infinity), which is just 0. Even if the dirac delta function doesn't fit that requirement, what about a function that does? The FT can't be 0 in that case either, right? (Apologies, I don't know how to use LaTeX)